# MongoDB : ensureIndex not working on both single key and composite keys

Tags: php, indexing, mongodb, batch-processing, unique-index

From hours I'm trying to add bulk data in my locally setup MongoDB collection, all is set except unique index for a key or keys :(

I've used this:

```
ensureIndex({appid:1, userid:1}, {unique:true, dropDups:true, background:true})
```

then this (coz I guess for whatever reason, multiple keys index is not working)

```
ensureIndex({userid:1}, {unique:true, dropDups:true, background:true})
```

after using above lines I tried to insert millions of rows from a php script (via both insert and batchInsert) and everytime duplicate userids are there :'( please please guide me on this :(

Comment: Hi! Did you manage to get this working in the end? I have the same issue, or I think at least. I can however enforce indexes by having `background: true` set while running the Mongo console admin. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that ensureIndex will not overwrite an existing index.  Instead, I believe you must first delete the existing index and THEN run ensureIndex.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a good idea to look and make sure the index was created. By default write operations (like creating indexes) are fire-and-forget and don't wait for error/success. This could be a bug in the driver (php client lib).

You can run

```
db.coll.getIndexes()
```

to list the indexes for the collection.

Comment: I was exactly thinking the same, its coz ov PHP client, coz at command line the indexes are creating properly and also throws errors on duplicates, but here again a mysterious attribute for dropDups...what is the purpose of this attribute if its not handling the duplicates and remove them according to the definition? strange things :-)

Comment: btw, I'm using RockMongo so at the same time I can see the indexes creation while inserting records (in my case), but they are not working for duplicates...